# Is it valid to change the order of tensors by changing their sign?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

**Can I change the order of tensors in an equation by changing their sign?**

So for example if I have something like:

$$-x^2\partial_\nu \partial_\mu $$

**Can I do the following?**

$$-x^2\partial_\nu \partial_\mu = -x_\rho x^\rho \partial_\nu \partial_\mu= x_\rho \partial_\nu x^\rho \partial_\mu $$

so that I can obtain:

$$x_\rho \delta^\rho _\nu \partial_\mu = x_\nu\partial_\mu$$

Could I potentially also change this final result? Like:

$$x_\nu\partial_\mu = -\partial_\mu x_\nu$$
**I can't find this rule anywhere but , for some reason, I have the idea I was told that the sign changing is permitted? Is that the case or is this not true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this rule does not exist. Furthermore, even if it was correct (it isn't) you have to remember that differential operators act on everything that they have on their right. You have to think of them applied to functions, so

$$
\partial_\mu x_\nu f = \eta_{\mu\nu}f + \boldsymbol{x_\nu\, \partial_\mu f}\,.
$$
See the second term? This, by the way, is the reason of the famous $[x,p] = i$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for integration by parts. If you introduce some scalar field $\phi(x)$ (vanishing as $x \to \infty$) that you act on with your derivatives, you can move a derivative $\partial_\nu$ off of the $\phi$ and onto the $x^2$, picking up a minus sign like so:

$$\int d^D x \,\,x^2\partial_\nu\partial_\mu \phi = -\int d^Dx\,\,(\partial_\nu x^2)(\partial_\mu \phi) = -\int d^Dx\,\,(2x_\nu)(\partial_\mu \phi)$$
Since $\phi$ was arbitrary, you could make a formal statement like $-2x_\nu \partial_\mu = x^2\partial_\nu\partial_\mu$ as long as you remember that this is only valid under an integral sign and under some mild assumptions about the behavior of $\phi$.